# Android depth buffer issue: Advice for anyone experiencing problem

Tags: android, opengl-es, depth, depth-buffer

I've wasted around 30 hours this week writing and re-writing code, believing that I had misunderstood how the OpenGL depth buffer works. Everything I tried, failed. I have now resolved my problem by finding what may be an error in the Android implementation of OpenGL.

See this API entry:

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glClearDepth.xml

> void glClearDepth(GLclampd depth);
>
> Specifies the depth value used when
>   the depth buffer is cleared. The
>   initial value is 1.

Android's implementation has two versions of this command:

- **glClearDepthx** which takes an integer
  value, clamped 0-1
- **glClearDepthf** which takes a floating
  point value, clamped 0-1

If you use **glClearDepthf(1)** then you get the results you would expect. If you use **glClearDepthx(1)**, as I was doing then you get different results. (Note that 1 is the default value, but calling the command with the argument 1 produces different results than not calling it at all.) Quite what is happening I do not know, but the depth buffer was being cleared to a value different from what I had specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try passing `65536` to [`glClearDepthx()`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glClearDepth.xml).

`GLfixed` is S15.16 fixed-point, so `1.0` is represented by `2^16` or `65536`.

Also, you linked to the regular OpenGL documentation, not the [OpenGL ES 1.1](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/) docs.

Comment: That produces the expected results. Thank you. The documentation really should be more clear. I notice that the ES 1.1 site also states that the maximum value for glClearDepthx() is 1.